# AJAX asynchronisity & returning

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3

Trying to create a map with specific routes with infowindows populated by ajax data. The standard data such as addresses and such taken from an mysql/ajax request, not real-time data, stored. But I'd like to also do an ajax request to get departure times etc on the fly.

The code goes like this:

```
//initialise function is ok, its the latter function where the problem resides
function initialise(){
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),{
        center: {lat: 37.7833, lng:-122.4167},
        zoom: 10
    });
$('.route_button input').click(function() {
    clearMarkers();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'include/routeinfo_ajax.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {route: $(this).attr('name')},
        success: function(response) {
            setMarkerDetails(response);
            for(var i = 0; i<route.length;i++){
                placeMarkers(map, route[i]);
                placePolylines(map, route[i]);
            }
            //reset polyline path
            path = [];
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    })
});

function placeMarkers(map, route){
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(route[2], route[3]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position:latLng,
        map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
//onclick I'd like both the info variable and the etd variable to be in the same infowindow, at the moment I can only get one or t'other.
        $.ajax({
            url: 'include/etd.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {orig: route[1]},
            success: function(response) {
                var etd = 'Time: '+response.getElementsByTagName('time')[0].innerHTML
                +'<br>Minutes till departure: '+response.getElementsByTagName('minutes')[0].innerHTML
                +'<br>Platform: '+response.getElementsByTagName('platform')[0].innerHTML
                +'<br>Direction: '+response.getElementsByTagName('direction')[0].innerHTML
                +'<br>Destination: '+response.getElementsByTagName('destination')[0].innerHTML;
                return etd;
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
        infowindow.close();
        //etd is not defined
        var info = '<h2>'+route[0]+'</h2><p>'+route[4]+'<br>'+route[5]+'<br>'+route[6]+'<br>'+etd+'</p>';
        infowindow.setContent(info);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
```

Now as expected the returned `etd` variable results in `undefined` due to the asynchronous nature, I understand that. What I cant seem to get around to is a solution. I attempted a callback function but that didn't work, it resulted in a `b.get is not a function` error when I tried to place the infowindow properties within said function. I think it messed with the route variable, honestly I'm not quite sure.

Once again any help appreciated.

Note, my attempt of a fix:

```
    function getVar(fn) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'include/etd.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {orig: route[1]},
            success: function(response) {
                var etd = 'Time: '+response.getElementsByTagName('time')[0].innerHTML
                +'Minutes till departure: '+response.getElementsByTagName('minutes')[0].innerHTML
                +'<br>Platform: '+response.getElementsByTagName('platform')[0].innerHTML
                +'<br>Direction: '+response.getElementsByTagName('direction')[0].innerHTML
                +'<br>Destination: '+response.getElementsByTagName('destination')[0].innerHTML;
                fn(etd);
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
    } 
    getVar(function(etd) {
        var info = '<h2>'+route[0]+'</h2><p>'+route[4]+'<br>'+route[5]+'<br>'+route[6]+'<br>'+etd+'</p>';
        infowindow.close();
        infowindow.setContent(info);
        infowindow.open(map, this);

    });
});
```

}

Comment: First off, you may replace all of the `response.getElementsByTagName` with `$(response).find('tagName')` as when you use jQuery, make the most of it.

Comment: Totally forgot about that thank-you

Comment: And see if [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/592whk52/1/) makes any difference.

Comment: `getVar.done is not a function` error I'm afraid

Comment: Sure, and how [about this](http://jsfiddle.net/592whk52/3/)

Comment: Thank-you but `b.get is not a function` again @LShetty. Both sets of data just do not want to meet.

Comment: The `this` in your callback function is not the same as the one in your original code.